# Python: Do not map empty result of multiprocessing.Pool( )

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

Program have function that may return None value, for minimize spend time this function calling in parallel workers.
In code below, result of this function have the "None" values, how to exclude this is values from the "ret"?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,multiprocessing,time
maxNumber = sys.maxint+2

def numGen():
    cnt=0
    while cnt < maxNumber:
        cnt +=1
        yield cnt

def oddCheck(num):
    global maxNumber
    # time.sleep(1)
    if not bool(num%1000000):
        print "[%s%%] %s" % (int((num/maxNumber)*100),num)
    if num%2:
        return num

pool = multiprocessing.Pool( )
if sys.maxint < maxNumber:
    print "We have problem on %s"%sys.maxint
    # quit()
ret = pool.imap(oddCheck, numGen())
pool.close()
pool.join()

for x in ret:
    print x
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`oddCheck` returns `None` when `num` is not a even number (you do not have a return statement in this case, so `None` will be returned).

If you want to avoid `None` results, just use a list comprehension to filter them:

```
ret = [x for x in pool.imap(oddCheck, numGen()) if x is not None]
```

It should do the trick ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent the `None` from being part of the `pool.imap()` return result rather than filtering it afterwards?

Comment: The problem with this solution is it resolves the iterator. So if you're using this from a loop instead of immediately starting to work on it, you'll have to wait for all workers to finish.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your desire to filter out `None` during multiprocessing rather than afterwards? I feel that this must exist, but I am just not searching for the right keywords.